# Fitbit App sideload fails with Internal error

Tags: fitbit

I am trying to develop an app for Fitbit Versa 3. I am able to connect from my VS code to Fitbit OS simulator, but when I try to install the app using the following two commands:

```
npx fitbit
bi
```

I get an error

```
Loaded appID:c25295d1-e4d6-43e5-a93a-b8d3bef90830 buildID:0x097ede643c977ca5
App requires a device, connecting...
Auto-connecting only known device: Versa 3 Simulator
App requires a phone, connecting...
Auto-connecting only known phone: Simulator
Sideloading app: starting...
Install failed: Internal Error
```

There are no details on what the Internal error is for. Has someone encountered this error before?

Things I have tried:

- Restarting Fitbit OS Simulator and VS code
- Generate a new App Id for the Fitbit app
- Ensuring that both the Fitbit OS simulator and VS code are connected to same Fitbit account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://community.fitbit.com/t5/SDK-Development/Simulator-SSL-Problem/m-p/5003032/highlight/true#M16148

It is a simulation problem, I believe. You have to delete the cacert.pem in the simulator, and replace with a new and updated version of cacert.pem in the simulator folder for Versa 3 . Click on this forum discussion to find the cacert.pem download and instructions. The simulator has been broken for a while as announced in November on the Fitbit Development Twitter.